# ptrace is not working in 64 bit

Tags: c, linux

please anyone tell me that why the bellow code is not working on 64 bit linux
parent process will change the data value in tchild by ptrace.initially child process executed normally and suspend the process by signal and change the data in tchild program.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <signal.h>
  #include <sys/ptrace.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <sys/types.h> 
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <wait.h>
  #include <linux/user.h>
  int main()
  {
      struct user_regs_struct regs;
      int pid, status;  /* process id & status */
      pid = fork();   /* create new process */
      int data;

      if(pid == 0) { 
     ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
      if(execl("/home/neeraj/neerajgit/ptrace/tchild", "tchild", 0) == -1)         
         {
          fprintf(stderr, "exec err \n");  /* err msg */
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
     }
    else if(pid < 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "fork  err\n");
    }
    else {  
       wait(&status);

       if(WIFSTOPPED(status) ) { printf("child stopped \n"); } 

       printf("parent start\n");
       kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
        data = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0,&regs); printf("%d\n", data);
        data = 30; 
       ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid,   201010  + 8 , &data );  




    ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, 201010 + 8,  NULL); printf("%d\n", data);
    printf("child started\n");
    printf("%ld \n", regs.rbx);
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);
    sleep(5);
    }

    this is the tchild program

    #include <stdio.h>
   #include <sys/ptrace.h>
   int data;
   data = 20;  /* tchild main */
   int main()
    {       printf("child started \n");
    while(data != 30) ;
    printf("child stopped %d\n", data);
   }
```

Comment: (1) How do you know that the variable `data` is at address `201010 + 8` in the child process? (2) When compiling `tchild`, the compiler is entitled to assume that `data` never changes.  I bet if you dump the assembly for `tchild` you will see an unconditional infinite loop that doesn't even look at `data`.

Comment: (3) Everything to do with `ptrace` is [black art](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/b/blackart.html). Are you _certain_ that there is _no other way_ to accomplish your larger goal?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to attach the target process in the parent processus. You also need to wait for the traced program to stop **after** sending the signal.

```
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
wait(&status);
printf("parent start\n");

if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) { printf("child stopped \n"); } 

data = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0,&regs); printf("%d\n", data);
data = 30; 
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid,   201010  + 8 , &data );  )
```